# Delete records from cassandra table using both primary & non-primary keys

Tags: php, codeigniter, cassandra

I am new to cassandra database. I am using [cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.10 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0].

I want to delete records from a particular columnfamily by using both primary key constraint also non- primary key constraint;

Please suggest me or give me a solution to achieve this.

Below I mentioned my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE gb_admin_login_history (
  au_id int,
  lh_id int,
  au_username text,
  login_ip_address text,  
  login_time text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((au_id), lh_id)
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 
  AND  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND  comment='' 
  AND  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.100000 
  AND  gc_grace_seconds=864000 
  AND  index_interval=128 
  AND  read_repair_chance=0.000000 
  AND  replicate_on_write='true' 
  AND  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' 
  AND  default_time_to_live=0 ANDspeculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' 
  AND  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 
  AND  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} 
  AND  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

Comment: show your table definition

Comment: "I want to delete records from a particular columnfamily by using both primary key constraint also non-primary key constraint"- I'm confused...are you saying that `DELETE FROM gb_admin_login_history WHERE au_id=? AND lh_id=?;` doesn't work for you?

Comment: No I am not meaning like that.DELETE FROM gb_admin_login_history WHERE au_id=?;  or  DELETE FROM gb_admin_login_history WHERE lh_id=?;